# Arduino IDE 1.8.8 built in 1.2.1 Temboo Library?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, shields, arduino-leonardo, arduino-yun

I am weirded about the built-in "latest Temboo library" with the latest Arduino IDE; when a previous older code says to download the latest Temboo version < 2? 
(which I found this: https://temboo.com/download)

http://wirebeings.com/arduino-intruder-alarm.html

I am using Arduino Uno or Arduino Leonardo + an iDuino Yun shield to recreate the experiment above.

I keep getting errors like this:

[No matching function for call to 'TembooChoreo::TembooChoreo()'? TembooChoreo SendSMSChoreo; Error Help](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/60674/no-matching-function-for-call-to-temboochoreotemboochoreo-temboochoreo-se?noredirect=1#comment128974_60674)

Arduino: 1.8.8 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Leonardo"

Build options changed, rebuilding all
In file included from C:\Users\user\Documents\Arduino\intruderAlarmTest\intruderAlarmTest.ino:6:0:

E:\arduino\arduino-1.8.8\libraries\Temboo\src/Temboo.h:86:43: error: expected identifier before '(' token

#define TEMBOO_ERROR_ACCOUNT_MISSING      (201)

```
                                       ^
```

E:\arduino\arduino-1.8.8\libraries\Temboo\src/TembooCoAPEdgeDevice.h:264:13: note: in expansion of macro 'TEMBOO_ERROR_ACCOUNT_MISSING'

```
         TEMBOO_ERROR_ACCOUNT_MISSING       = 201,

         ^
```

E:\arduino\arduino-1.8.8\libraries\Temboo\src/Temboo.h:86:43: error: expected '}' before '(' token

#define TEMBOO_ERROR_ACCOUNT_MISSING      (201)

```
                                       ^
```

E:\arduino\arduino-1.8.8\libraries\Temboo\src/TembooCoAPEdgeDevice.h:264:13: note: in expansion of macro 'TEMBOO_ERROR_ACCOUNT_MISSING'

```
         TEMBOO_ERROR_ACCOUNT_MISSING       = 201,

         ^
```

E:\arduino\arduino-1.8.8\libraries\Temboo\src/Temboo.h:86:44: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

#define TEMBOO_ERROR_ACCOUNT_MISSING      (201)

```
                                        ^
```

E:\arduino\arduino-1.8.8\libraries\Temboo\src/TembooCoAPEdgeDevice.h:264:13: note: in expansion of macro 'TEMBOO_ERROR_ACCOUNT_MISSING'

```
         TEMBOO_ERROR_ACCOUNT_MISSING       = 201,

         ^
```

E:\arduino\arduino-1.8.8\libraries\Temboo\src/Temboo.h:86:44: error: expected ')' before numeric constant

#define TEMBOO_ERROR_ACCOUNT_MISSING      (201)

```
                                        ^
```

E:\arduino\arduino-1.8.8\libraries\Temboo\src/TembooCoAPEdgeDevice.h:264:13: note: in expansion of macro 'TEMBOO_ERROR_ACCOUNT_MISSING'

```
         TEMBOO_ERROR_ACCOUNT_MISSING       = 201,

         ^
```

In file included from C:\Users\user\Documents\Arduino\intruderAlarmTest\intruderAlarmTest.ino:7:0:

E:\arduino\arduino-1.8.8\libraries\Temboo\src/TembooCoAPEdgeDevice.h: In member function 'char* TembooCoAPChoreo::getResponseData()':

E:\arduino\arduino-1.8.8\libraries\Temboo\src/TembooCoAPEdgeDevice.h:247:41: error: 'm_respData' was not declared in this scope

```
     char* getResponseData() {return m_respData;}

                                     ^
```

E:\arduino\arduino-1.8.8\libraries\Temboo\src/TembooCoAPEdgeDevice.h: In member function 'char* TembooCoAPChoreo::getHTTPResponseCode()':

E:\arduino\arduino-1.8.8\libraries\Temboo\src/TembooCoAPEdgeDevice.h:248:45: error: 'm_httpCodeStr' was not declared in this scope

```
     char* getHTTPResponseCode() {return m_httpCodeStr;}

                                         ^
```

E:\arduino\arduino-1.8.8\libraries\Temboo\src/TembooCoAPEdgeDevice.h: At global scope:

E:\arduino\arduino-1.8.8\libraries\Temboo\src/TembooCoAPEdgeDevice.h:277:5: error: expected unqualified-id before 'protected'

```
 protected:

 ^
```

E:\arduino\arduino-1.8.8\libraries\Temboo\src/TembooCoAPEdgeDevice.h:280:27: error: 'm_client' declared as reference but not initialized

```
     TembooCoAPClient& m_client;

                       ^
```

E:\arduino\arduino-1.8.8\libraries\Temboo\src/TembooCoAPEdgeDevice.h:311:5: error: expected unqualified-id before 'protected'

```
 protected:

 ^
```

E:\arduino\arduino-1.8.8\libraries\Temboo\src/TembooCoAPEdgeDevice.h:314:1: error: expected declaration before '}' token

};

^

exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino Leonardo.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.

Update: 
I found that   by adding #include TembooYunShield.h
and TembooYunShieldChoreo  SendSMSChoreo;
instead of TembooChereo SendSMSChoreo;

fixes most of the errors

except the @Temboo and @Twilio problem.

Comment: Sounds like they made a mess of it. Just delete it and download the official latest version of the library manually.

Comment: yeah how, I don't even understand there are different programming languages that I extracted from .zip or .jar. to raw folders and files and replaced my older Temboo with it.

but it still doesn't work, I can't make https://temboo.com/download seem to work so I stick with the built in latest 1.2.1 Temboo library from Arduino 1.8.8.

Comment: Can anyone help me with this temboo? Who is really knowledgable with this?

Comment: https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/users/84/jfpoilpret

https://stackexchange.com/users/2147199/cormac-driver

Please, any of you kind sirs help me regarding the temboo latest version issue? to be uploaded to arduino-1.8.8\libraries\Temboo?

anyone?

Comment: The problem appears to be because you are compiling for the Leonardo. If I compile for the Yun the examples work. If I compile for the Leonardo they fail with the messages you see.

Comment: I think the problem is that if you compile for the Yun it assumes a connection through the Yun and works. If you compile for anything else you have to give it details of your internet connection (WiFi shield, Ethernet shield, etc) and work in a completely different way. Since you have a Yun shield you would have to compile it for a Yun. Theoretically there should be no difference between a Yun and a Leonardo + Yun shield.